# UITableViewCell Separator Style doesn't change

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am making something like facebook app's left panel search feature. I have two UITableViewControllers. I take a tableView from one of them and put it above another one, when user taps on UISearchBar to show search results. When I create this second UITableViewController, I tell, that it's separator style will be none in ViewDidLoad method:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

And then, after I put it's tableView above the first UITableViewController's view, it is empty at first, since no data is yet entered to the UISearchBar. And there are no any separators. But then, when user enters any letter and table data has some records, the separator style returns to the default one (white lines).

So, for some reason, my second controller forgets, what should be the separator style and displays after the reload of table view separators again. `What can be the reason?`

Edit: 
This is how I create my second UITableViewController and take it's tableView to put on the first controller's view:

```
    - (UIView *)searchResultsView
{
    if (! _searchResultsView) {

        _searchResultsView = self.searchResultsViewController.tableView;
        _searchResultsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, self.view.frame.size.height-44);
    }

    return _searchResultsView;
}


- (SearchResultsViewController *)searchResultsViewController
{
    if (! _searchResultsViewController) {

        _searchResultsViewController = [[SearchResultsViewController alloc] init];
        _searchResultsViewController.searchBar = _searchBar;

    }

    return _searchResultsViewController;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{   
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchResultsView];
}
```

Screenshot:

This is how it looks, when there is no data for table view:

[image]

As you see, there are no separators.

This is how it looks, when there is data. I have deleted cell contents. As you see, there are white separators.

[image]

Comment: IS that "tableView" is the object of UITabViewController?

Comment: It is object of the second UITableViewController which is put on top of view of first UITableViewController, when user wants to search something. He searches not in the same table data. That is why I use another table view controller. It all looks like facebook app's search it the left side panel.

Comment: @wzbozon can you show your code as well as the screen shot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What I feel is height for tableCell and fixed height are different, Just a guess..

Comment: Flappy, what do you mean by fixed height? Yes, the height is not default in my second tableView.

Comment: What is your problem actually? U dont need the separator even after u start searching.Right?

Comment: NSUserDefault, yes. But I solved the problem! The problem was that I used UISearchController and it creates it's own tableView. So I had even 3 tableViews there. After I removed UISearchController and it's delegate methods, everything started working. Now I take a string from UISearchBar and transfer it to my second UITableViewController. UISearchController is not needed there.

Comment: @wzbozon: Ho great!!!! Happy coding:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used UISearchController and it creates it's own tableView. So I had even 3 tableViews there. After I removed UISearchController and it's delegate methods, everything started working. Now I take a string from UISearchBar and transfer it to my second UITableViewController. UISearchController is not needed there.

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *searchString = [_searchBar.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    self.searchResultsViewController.searchString = searchString;

    return YES;
}
```

And I use custom setter for searchString in second UITableViewController:

```
- (void)setSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    _searchString = searchString;

    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];`